# How to enforce --ignore-platform-reqs only applied on 1 package during composer update

Tags: php, composer-php

Currently, I have the following `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "scientiamobile/wurfl-api": "*",    <-- I want this package to ignore PHP requirement
    "twig/twig": "1.*",                 <-- I want this package to obey PHP 5.3.3 requirement
    "guzzle/guzzle": "*",               <-- I want this package to obey PHP 5.3.3 requirement
    ...         
},
"config": {
  "platform": {
    "php": "5.3.3"
  }
},
```

During `compose.phar update`, I want all packages to obey PHP 5.3.3 requirement, except `scientiamobile/wurfl-api` package.

If I run using `compose.phar update --ignore-platform-reqs`, all other packages will no longer obey PHP 5.3.3 rule, which is not what I want.

I also don't want to run `composer.phar update "scientiamobile/wurfl-api" --ignore-platform-reqs`, as I want the update operation performed on all packages.

May I know, what is the correct way to achive so?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I cannot imagine that this makes any sense, so please explain your situation more in order to allow alternative solutions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?